# 1/F distribution equality significance level

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, f-distribution

A question about equality

$$F_{r_{1},r_{2},\alpha}=\frac{1}{F_{r_{2},r_{1},1-\alpha}}$$

We know if $X\sim\chi^{2}\left(  r_{1}\right)  ,~Y\sim\chi^{2}\left(
r_{2}\right)  $ and $X,~Y$ independent then

$$\frac{X/r_{1}}{Y/r_{2}}=F\implies\frac{Y/r_{2}}{X/r_{1}}=\frac{1}{F}$$
distributed. But how can we get $1-\alpha$ instead of $\alpha$. Do i have to get
this result using probability density function and transformations or is there
another sensible explanation?

Comment: Taking reciprocals is an order-reversing operation. It might help to draw a picture of the relevant tails of the two distributions.

Comment: What do you mean by $1-\alpha$? Are you talking about critical values ($F^{-1}(\alpha)$) on the corresponding $F$ distributions you've obtained? Otherwise $\alpha$ is a prespecified significance level, and is conventionally taken to be 0.05 unless otherwise specified.